# LTI Multi-input Control System. Proof that controllability holds given a state feedback.

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

The question is : Prove that (A, B) is controllable if and only if (A + BK, B) is controllable for all K.

My proof thus far:

- Let $u=kx +v$
- Consider the **Im(Qc) = Im(B) + (A+BK)*Im(B) + ... + (A+BK)^n-1 * Im(B)**
- I know that it can be shown that for any vector 'v' contained in R^n that **Im(B) + (A+BK)*v = Im(B) + A*v**...however I am not sure how to show this

My idea is to show that **Im(B) + (A+BK)*v*** is contained in **Im(B) + Av** and vice versa.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, we can use the following property: $(A,B)$ is controllable if and only if $[\matrix{A-\lambda\mathbb{I} & B}]$ has full row rank for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$.

Then we can write
$$[\matrix{(A+BK)-\lambda\mathbb{I} & B}]=[\matrix{A-\lambda\mathbb{I} & B}]\left[\matrix{\mathbb{I} & 0\\K & \mathbb{I}}\right]$$
from which the desired property is obtained.

Comment: Is this property extended for time-varying K(t)?

Answer (score 0):

Take $y,z \in \operatorname{Im} B$. We need to show that $y + (A+BK)z \in \operatorname{Im} B + A \operatorname{Im} B$, i.e. there exist $u,v \in \operatorname{Im} B$ such that $y+ (A+BK)z = u + Av$. Indeed, take $v=z$ and $u = y+BKz \in \operatorname{Im} B$.

For the other direction let $u,v \in \operatorname{Im} B$ arbitrary and show that there exist $y,z \in \operatorname{Im} B$ such that $u + Av = y + (A+BK)z$. Taking $z=v$ and $y=u-BKv \in \operatorname{Im} B$ we can conclude the result.